Jira Servicemanagemet Assets Importer Mapping Error - Something went wrong. Contact administrator
My problem is based on the jira Mapping Endpoint. Every Time I want to update or upload my Mapping/Schema, I get this Error Message: Something went wrong. Contact administrator with the Error Code 500 or it works, and I simply dont know what the Error is, if im doing something wrong or if Atlassian has some Problems on their end.
This is my Code, the Mapping is a JSON object, which works, because I got the Importer Working, but as I said, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesnt.
response = await api.asUser().requestJira(route`/jsm/assets/workspace/${workspaceId}/v1/importsource/${importId}/mapping`, {
            method: "PUT",
            body: JSON.stringify(mapping),
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        });

BTW. I first check if there is already a mapping, and then I use the PUT or PATCH HTTP-Request if I need to update it or create it like in the Atlassian Dokumentation: https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/assets/rest/api-group-importsource/#api-group-importsource
I already tried to change some stuff in the request code block, and the mapping as well, but nothing worked, its just luck based, if it works or not.
